# Is the Template Method Pattern the best solution for shared Soap methods?

Tags: php, zend-framework, design-patterns, soap

I have a number of Soap Server classes most of which will need to implement 3 methods:

```
ping() // something to bounce a signal off to prove it has been reached
getCredentials($creds) // credentials to check sets session value
getCaller() // for logging, uses session value
```

As they form part of the WSDL defn they need to be public.

I am fairly sure this (I have christened it a Soaplogin) would need to be an abstract class (because it must never be instantiated on its own)

The concrete classes which extend then this core then have their own methods, none of which are shared.

I am searching for the best type of Pattern to use and am getting a bit confused, though I think a Template Method just about fits the bill - but I could just plain extend the SoapLogin class.

What advice can you give me on the best pattern to use, and maybe a preferred name for this class.

(while this uses ZF1 components it does not use full blown MVC - in case that was of importance)

Comment: A thing I found useful every single time is to include a way to ask the server which software version it is running. Your `ping()` function looks like it should do it.

Comment: Perhaps incorrectly, I use ping() to simply prove the service is reachable.  I tested with wsdl caching turned OFF, no wsdl? die(); But  once wsdl caching is turned on I couldn't think of another way of proving the service was up/reachable. I wanted to separate the login message from the "proof of life" message.  The client also logs the getCredentials response string... but yeah, I guess it could return version no...

Comment: Completely agree. Checking those basics is essential for efficient debugging, and I like your idea of ping. I'm not sure whether emitting a version info for ping is in order, or if that should be put into a `getVersionInfo` method (which can act as a heartbeat check function, too), but I know from experience with plenty of soap services that you actually want to know it's version EASILY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefer composition over inheritance.

What you really do is you create completely independent interfaces that only by chance happen to have the same methods.

Fine. Generic methods that always do the same - that should be in a class of it's own. But not ONE class for all these methods! One class per method!

You can then add all these method classes to your server classes, and also add all the special functions the same way.

That way you can combine any of the generic functions in any way, and add another only to one API if needed.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern could be a good solution if you just want to create several soap connect.

An other one could be to use interface. It will tell your program that every class that implements SoapItf (for example, rename it if you want) are able to perform soap method.

If you look for an evolutive application, maybe you'll need to connect with Rest webservice after so you can create an abstract class Werbservice, two class Soap and Rest that extends it and this two class implements interface SoapItf ans RestItf respectively.

This method helps using polymorphism, an important concept in OOP.

[image: class diagram]

In this case I can add method to Soap or Rest without  changing both.

After that if you have specificity with Soap like in your example, you could extends Soap class. It will be easier to evolve the application and using package architecture (interesting if you work with namespaces)

Comment: SOAP and REST are two concepts that might not really align well. Thinking the way SOAP works will usually result in designing very bad REST services.

Comment: I didn't say the contrary, I just made a design that call a same class Webservice but Rest and Soap extends this class just for semantic problems no more. They don't do the same thing and that's why we use different interface but they are both webservice

Comment: I'll show you a UML representation because it seams not clear. I'll edit my answer

Comment: My point is: The difference between SOAP and Rest is not only semantic. They are usually too different to fit into a concept of polymorphism. Of course you can define a Rest service that only acts on POST requests, and requires the method to be called to be present in the HTTP header, and you need not really use XML as the data format but could also use JSON - but this is no real Rest service, but a Soap service in disguise. The API of such a Rest service would be considered very badly designed.

Comment: I really don't knwo where is the problem. I've already used it in real application and there is no problem. It's not a design problem if you define your class correctly. But answer with an other diagram maybe I will agree with you.

Comment: I have to add that I'm ok with the difference between Soap and Rest request but this is not a problem because you don't define it inside top class. To make complex Request you can create Response and Request  class that will do the Job. It is quite simple to add

Comment: The thing is: Soap is level 0 in the [Richardson Maturity Model](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html), while RESTful APIs usually try to be level 3 and end up being only level 2 most of the time. Try to show me an example of your dual interface approach, and I'd try to show you the problem I see.

Comment: I just had a look at the link you gave. Maybe we could discuss about it using chat.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you can use template pattern to manage a common resource that is spreadable in sub-classes. For instance, you have a soaplogin common abstract class and that might have some resource that can be used by most of the sub-classes. Then it's better to manage that resource in super-class and pass the callback in subclass to use the resource of the super-class. Advantage is that you are managing resource at a single place.

For example, I have a common resource in my super-class. I can create a callback passing resource as a parameter.

```
interface ResourceCallback {
     T call(Resource resource);
}
```

Then can define a abstract method in super-class like as doWithResource(ResourceCallback callback) and all the subclass can now use the resource with their own implementation of their methods.